# TypeError at /doLogin authenticate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

that is the error I get when I tried to log in
I don't really know if something is missing in my login code
please help me review this code
this is my

views.py

> ```
> import datetime
> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
> from django.shortcuts import render
> from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
> from student_management_app.EmailBackEnd import EmailBackEnd
>
> # Create your views here.
> def showDemoPage(request):
>     return render(request, "demo.html")
>
> def ShowLoginPage(request):
>     return render(request, "login_page.html")
>
> def doLogin(request):
>     if request.method!="POST":
>         return HttpResponse("<h2>Method Not Allowed</h2>")
>     else:
>         user=EmailBackEnd.authenticate(request,username=request.POST.get("email"),password=request.POST.get("password"))
>         if user!=None:
>             login(request,user)
>             return HttpResponse("Email : "+request.POST.get("email")+ "password
> ```
>
> :"+request.POST.get("password"))
> else:
> return HttpResponse("Invalid Login")
>
> ```
> def GetUserDetails(request):
>     if request.user!=None:
>         return HttpResponse("User :"+request.user.email+" usertype : "+request.user.user_type)
>     else:
>         return HttpResponse("Please Login First")
>
> def logout_user(request):
>     logout(request)
>     return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
> ```

EmailBackEnd.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


class EmailBackEnd(ModelBackend):
    def authentication(self,request username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel=get_user_model()
        try:
            user=UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

Urls.py Code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from student_management_app import views
from student_management_system import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('demo', views.showDemoPage),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.ShowLoginPage),
    path('get_user_details', views.GetUserDetails),
    path('logout_user', views.logout_user),
    path('doLogin', views.doLogin)
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)+static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Share you backend authentication code

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is in Email Backend Authentication code. if you notice

```
class EmailBackEnd(ModelBackend):
    def authentication(self,request username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
```

You missing a comma after request, it should be like

```
class EmailBackEnd(ModelBackend):
    def authentication(self,request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
```

Also avoid calling the Authentication backend directly. You should import the default auth backend and add your custom to settings like

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def doLogin(request):
    if request.method!="POST":
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Method Not Allowed</h2>")
    else:
        user= authenticate(request,username=request.POST.get("email"),password=request.POST.get("password"))
        if user!=None:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponse("Email : "+request.POST.get("email")+ "password
```

And add your custom backend in the settings like

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'student_management_app.EmailBackEnd.EmailBackEnd',   
]
```

That makes sure that django goes through all the backends and uses one that works for your use case

Comment: many thank sir, edited the code as instructed this is the error I get when I run my sever



ImportError at /doLogin
Module "django.contrib.auth.backends" does not define a "EmailBackend" attribute/class
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/doLogin
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: 
Module "django.contrib.auth.backends" does not define a "EmailBackend" attribute/class
Exception Location: C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py, line 22, in import_string

Comment: You should follow the naming convention of your files. It clearly shows that you don't have a method and or file called ```EmailBackend``` but instead ```EmailBackEnd```.

Answer (score 0):

`request` is passed as a first argument. Your first argument is `self`